# Find min,max in csv file in python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am trying to find min, max, average value of "Measured_Power" for all possible combination of rate . I have a lot of rates and frequencies (10 rates,10 frequencies). My csv file looks like:

```
Channel, Rate, Length, Frequency, Expected_Power, Measured_Power, Expected_Eq, Measured_Eq, 
A, 27, 1000, 100, 20, 20.16, <-23.0, -27.33,
A, 6, 1000, 100, 20, 20.12, <-23.0, -25.96,
A, 3, 1000, 100, 20, 20.05, <-23.0, -26.34,
A, 27, 1000, 101, 20, 20.11, <-23.0, -24.88,
A, 6, 1000, 101, 20, 20.26, <-23.0, -25.55,
A, 3, 1000, 101, 20, 20.08, <-23.0, -25.42,
B, 27, 1000, 100, 20, 20.5, <-23.0, -26.98,
B, 6, 1000, 100, 20, 20.21, <-23.0, -24.61,
B, 3, 1000, 100, 20, 20.17, <-23.0, -23.54,
...
```

I've tried:

```
import numpy

file = r'C:\data.csv'
c = numpy.genfromtxt(file,dtype='float',delimiter = ',',skiprows=1, skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, usecols=5,usemask=True)
print c.max()
print c.min()
```

I can find max and min, but how can I sort it by specific Channel,Rate and Frequency?. Any help would be appreciate.
Expected Out for Measured_Power:

```
Chanel, Rate, Max, Min, Average,
A, 3, .., .., ..,
A, 6, .., .., ..,
., ., .., .., ..,
., ., .., .., ..,
., ., .., .., ..,
A, 27,.., .., .., 

B, 3, .., .., ..,
B, 6, .., .., ..,
., ., .., .., ..,
., ., .., .., ..,
., ., .., .., ..,
B, 27,.., .., ..,
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: Are you wedded to `numpy`?  This sounds more like a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) problem to me.

Comment: I'm looking for simple solution (numpy, pandas etc..)

Comment: Maybe you want to make your example simpler, and write the full expected output, because it's still unclear.

Comment: Example with updated output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood what you want to get. You want to get the min, max and average `Measured_Power` for every possible combination of `Rate` and `Frequency`, right?

Well, you can do this quite fast with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')
grouped_measured_power = data.groupby([' Rate', ' Frequency'])[' Measured_Power']
min_measured_power_by_rate_and_freq = grouped_measured_power.min()
max_measured_power_by_rate_and_freq = grouped_measured_power.max()
average_measured_power_by_rate_and_freq = grouped_measured_power.mean()
```

And that's it! Note that I have put a space before the column names because there are spaces in your CSV file, but you may prefer to format the data file better.

For the record here are the outputs for your example

```
> min_measured_power_by_rate_and_freq
 Rate   Frequency
3      100           20.05
       101           20.08
6      100           20.12
       101           20.26
27     100           20.16
       101           20.11
Name:  Measured_Power, dtype: float64

> max_measured_power_by_rate_and_freq
 Rate   Frequency
3      100           20.05
       101           20.08
6      100           20.21
       101           20.26
27     100           20.50
       101           20.11
Name:  Measured_Power, dtype: float64

> average_measured_power_by_rate_and_freq
 Rate   Frequency
3      100           20.050
       101           20.080
6      100           20.165
       101           20.260
27     100           20.330
       101           20.110
Name:  Measured_Power, dtype: float64
```

The result is a multi-indexed structure... you may want to [unstack it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking), too.

**EDIT:**

Just remembered that you can actually do even better by applying several aggregation functions at once, so you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')
grouped_measured_power = data.groupby([' Rate', ' Frequency'])[' Measured_Power']
result = grouped_measured_power.aggregate({'min': np.min,
                                           'max': np.max,
                                           'average': np.mean})
```

And you would directly get everything together:

```
> result
                  average    max    min
 Rate  Frequency                       
3     100          20.050  20.05  20.05
      101          20.080  20.08  20.08
6     100          20.165  20.21  20.12
      101          20.260  20.26  20.26
27    100          20.330  20.50  20.16
      101          20.110  20.11  20.11
```

Comment: Thank you for the post,comments and all. I tried your solution, but I have technical issues in pandas with old version of numpy ,compiling and installation environments. Is it possible use csv reader ?

Comment: It *should be possible* to use `csv.reader` to create the data frame, but seems like an unnecessary mess... What kind of issues are you having? You should be able to install numpy and pandas without much problem (what is your OS?), and anyway you need it for the group and aggregation steps.

Comment: I solved my issues with pandas. Uninstalling old version of numpy and installing new one solved it. javidcf, your solution works for me!! Thanks!!